# Proving the sequence exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $a\in\mathbb R$. Assume $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ with $n\ge1$, we have $\left(a-\dfrac1n , a+\dfrac1n\right)\cap(A\setminus\{a\})\ne\emptyset$. Then prove that there exists a sequence $(X_n)_n$ in $A$ such that it has no repeating terms and this sequence converges to $a$.

I thought that by assumption we get |xn-a|<1/n and since 1/n is convergent sequence, i applied the formal definition of convergence of sequences with epsilon-delta then i concluded xn is convergent to a. But i dont think that my proof is complete.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I thought that by assumption we get |xn-a|<1/n and since 1/n is convergent sequence, i applied the formal definition of convergence of sequences with epsilon-delta then i concluded xn is convergent to a. But i dont think that my proof is complete.

Comment: That's part of the idea, but I think to get a full proof, you actually have to _create_ the sequence $X_n$, and then show that it 1) converges to $a$, and 2) doesn't have any repeated terms. As in, you have to tell us (the readers of your proof) what each term of the sequence is and demonstrate (through proof) that it has the properties required. Constructing a thing is probably the most common way to show that that thing exists, and in this case I think that's the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $x_n = a+2^{-n}$. Then $a-\frac1n<a+2^{-n}<a+\frac1n$ and clearly $x_n\to a$ with no repeating terms.